# Gorilla sessions cookie usage with a wrapper

Tags: go, gorilla

I am using a basic wrapper in a web application like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/gorilla/sessions"
)

const (
    PORT = "8083"
)

func navbarWrapper(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "header")
        h(w, r) // call original function
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "footer")
    }
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/cookie_write", navbarWrapper(cookie_write))

    hostname, _ := os.Hostname()
    log.Printf("Listening on port %s https://%s:%s/", PORT, hostname, PORT)
    http.ListenAndServe(":"+PORT, r)
}
```

I would like to set a cookie, but it is not being sent to the browser, but is also not providing an error

```
var (
    key   = []byte("16bytestufffffff")
    store = sessions.NewCookieStore(key)
)

func cookie_write(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, _ := store.Get(r, "session-name")

    session.Values["authenticated"] = true
    session.Values["stuff"] = "important info"
    if err := session.Save(r, w); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("error")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("worked?")
    }
}
```

If I remove the wrapper, then it works fine and I can see the cookie being generated in the browser:

```
r.HandleFunc("/cookie_write", cookie_write)
```

I know I must not be saving the session correctly, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: I figured out this is related to the need of the session.Save(r, w) to be executed before anything is written to the response.  The wrapper in this case is writing to the response first.  So now I need to figure out the best-practice way to handle situations like this

Comment: I wouldn't use middleware like that to write parts of the response. You're probably better off doing all the rendering in one place, separately from the middleware (which is mostly about http).

Comment: So what is the customary way of including a common header/navigation bar/etc to all the pages of a webapp ?

Comment: Nested templates are pretty common for that. For example this seems to be a pretty good guide on how to do that: https://hackernoon.com/golang-template-2-template-composition-and-how-to-organize-template-files-4cb40bcdf8f6